# Adjacency list from Python dict

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I need to output a Python dictionary as an adjacency list: two columns, one – key, other – value; like this:

```
Key1, Value1
Key2, Value2
```

My dict contains strings as keys and integers as values. Was hoping that these lines would do the trick:

```
with open('Adjacency_list_indegrees.csv', 'wb') as ff:
    ff.write('\n')
    for key, values in deg_new.items():
        for value in values:
            ff.write('{},{}'.format(key, value))
            ff.write('\n')
```

However, I'm getting an error

```
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Does it mean that I have to transform integer values?

Comment: If your `deg_new` dict has ints as values, then your `values` variable is an int, so `for value in values` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: could you provide a sample csv format if yours?

Comment: You need to replace `for key, values in ...` with `for key, value in ...` and remove the second for loop.

Comment: @Lucas, thanks! I wasn't thinking too straight

Comment: You should check your dictionary. There are probably some values that are not lists/tuples, rather are ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop over the values, which are integers and not lists. You don't need to do that at all here; simplify your list to:

```
for key, value in deg_new.items():
    ff.write('{},{}\n'.format(key, value))
```

You also appear to be reinventing the wheel; there is a perfectly serviceable [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for this task:

```
import csv

with open('Adjacency_list_indegrees.csv', 'wb') as ff:
    writer = csv.writer(ff)
    ff.writerows(deg_new.items())
```

This writes all key-value pairs from `deg_new` in one go.

Answer (score 1):

`deg_new.items()` will give you *key, value pairs* from your dictionary.

E.g.

```
key1, value1
key2, value2
...
```

You don't have to then try and iterate through the values; you are already getting them one at a time.

So you can do this:

```
for key, value in deg_new.items():
    ff.write('{},{}\n'.format(key, value))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are probably some values that are not lists/tuples, rather are ints. For these instances you should use `try .. except`. Try the below code:

```
with open('Adjacency_list_indegrees.csv', 'wb') as ff:
    ff.write('\n')
    for key, values in deg_new.items():
        try:
            for value in values:
                ff.write('{},{}'.format(key, value))
                ff.write('\n')
        except:
            ff.write('{},{}'.format(key, values))
            ff.write('\n')
```

Comment: The OP states that the values are ints, not lists or tuples.